# compiler error while solving a question c++

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I was just giving my [contest over leetcode](https://leetcode.com/contest/weekly-contest-254/problems/array-with-elements-not-equal-to-average-of-neighbors/). I submitted my code as :

```
class Solution {
public:
    int numOfStrings(vector<string>& patterns, string word) {
        int cnt=0;
        
        for(int j=0;j<patterns.size();j++)
        {
            string ch=patterns[j];
            if(word.size()-ch.size()>=0)
            {for(int i=0;i<=word.size()-ch.size();i++)
            {
                if(ch==word.substr(i,ch.size()))
                {
                    cnt++;
                    break; 
                }
            }}
        }
        return cnt;
    }
};
```

which is not working as it showing some issue over the if statement `if(word.size()-ch.size()>=0)`. When this if statement is rewritten as `if(word.size()>=ch.size())` the code works completely fine.

If `word.size()-ch.size()>=0` and `word.size()>=ch.size()` are equivalent statements why doesn't yhe first one work?

Comment: if((word.size()-ch.size())>=0)

did you try putting () to priority first the computation before doing >= ?

Comment: Please see the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page. When asking questions about a specific error please include the specific error. The code you say is causing an error does not appear in your code.

Comment: @KentDelaCruzFueconcillo Those parentheses are redundant.

Comment: `.size()` returns a value of type `size_t`, which is unsigned. Subtracting two of them also yields a `size_t`. You're experiencing an underflow...